# wxPython RichTextCtrl with strikethrough

Tags: python, wxpython, strikethrough, richtextctrl

I want to set text with strike-through in `RichTextCtrl` of `wxPython`. But could not find any method like `BeginStrikethrough` or `SetStrikethrough`.

Is it possible to apply strike-through in `RichTextCtrl`? How?

**EDIT 1:**

`Font` with strike-through flag used with `BeginFont` and `EndFont` not giving strike-through effect

```
import wx
import wx.richtext as rt

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, 1, 'Testing strike-through')
        rtc = rt.RichTextCtrl(self, -1)
        rtc.WriteText("normal text")
        rtc.Newline()

        font = wx.FFont(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, face='Tahoma', flags=wx.FONTFLAG_STRIKETHROUGH)
        rtc.BeginFont(font)
        rtc.WriteText("This is strike-through")
        rtc.EndFont()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Output:**

[image: No strike-through in output]

Comment: I don't see that function, but it does have a `BeginFont` function, so you could create a font with strikethrough, and use it that way.

Comment: Hi @CorleyBrigman, I tried `BeginFont` and `EndFont` but not giving strike-through effect. See **EDIT 1** in question.

Comment: I haven't actually used it myself, but it looks like there is another answer below that works.

Comment: yes @CorleyBrigman, it worked 100% for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

1. You can use `font.SetStrikethrough(True)` with `wxpython2.9.4 or higher`, refer [This Link](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Font.html#Font.SetStrikethrough)
2. Otherwise: use `font.SetNativeFontInfoFromString(str)` to set the flag with Native info description.

Please check the following string to see the difference, only tested in windows:

desc without Strikethrough: 0;-16;0;0;0;400;0;0;`0`;1;0;0;2;32;Tahoma

desc with Strikethrough:   0;-16;0;0;0;400;0;0;`1`;1;0;0;2;32;Tahoma

Code:

```
import wx
import wx.richtext as rt

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, 1, 'Testing strike-through')
        rtc = rt.RichTextCtrl(self, -1)
        rtc.WriteText("normal text")
        rtc.Newline()

        font = wx.FFont(12, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, face='Tahoma', flags=wx.FONTFLAG_STRIKETHROUGH)

        info = font.GetNativeFontInfoDesc()
        info = self.setFontInfoStrikethrough(info)
        font.SetNativeFontInfoFromString(info)

        rtc.BeginFont(font)
        rtc.WriteText("This is strike-through")
        rtc.EndFont()

    def setFontInfoStrikethrough(self, info):
        print "orig:", info
        info = info.split(";")
        info[8] = r'1'
        info = ";".join(info)
        print "new :",info
        return info

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thnx @Jerry_Y, the **otherwise** approach you provided worked very well for me. I am using wxPython2.8 so its great that I dont need to upgrade to 2.9 or higher.. thnx again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text effect, this works with wxPython 2.8.12 too:

```
style = rt.TextAttrEx()
style.SetFlags(rt.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECTS)
style.SetTextEffects(rt.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_STRIKETHROUGH)
style.SetTextEffectFlags(rt.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_STRIKETHROUGH)
rtc.BeginStyle(style)
rtc.WriteText("This is strike-through")
rtc.EndStyle()
```

(tested on Linux)